# простой калькулятор сложения

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, form

Есть число в input value. В инпуте число можно увеличивать с помощью стрелочек, мне нужно данное число получить и умножать на 20. Допустим input value = 20, после умножаем на 20 и выводим в #price. Самая основная задача чтобы при нажатии на плюс(то есть +1) число умножалось сразу и выдавало результат (2*20 = 40, 3*20 = 60, с каждым разом как я нажимаю оно сразу на глазах увеличивается и также если минут (3*20 =60, 2*20 - 40). Подскажите с реализацией. Свои к сожалению без успешные попытки оставляю ниже. Буду благодарен за помощь!

```js
document.getElementById('[name=num]').addEventListener('input', function() {
        var output = document.getElementById('total-price');
        output.innerHTML = (this.value * 30);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get">
<input type="number" name="num" id="num-value" value="1">
<span id="price"></span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('[name=num]').addEventListener(...
```

или

```
document.getElementById('num-value').addEventListener(...
```

```js
document.getElementById('num-value').addEventListener('input', function() {
  var output = document.getElementById('price');
  output.innerHTML = this.value * 30;
});
```

```html
<form method="get">
  <input type="number" name="num" id="num-value" value="1">
  <span id="price"></span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const numValueNode = document.getElementById('num-value');
const output = document.getElementById('price');

numValueNode.addEventListener('input', calc);

function calc() {
  output.innerHTML = numValueNode.value * 30;
}

calc();
```

```html
<form method="get">
  <input type="number" name="num" id="num-value" value="1">
  <span id="price"></span>
</form>
```